# jQuery Validate on a Complex Rule: Turn off automatically when not applicable but not on startup

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

In the script below I have a complex jQuery-Validate rule which fires if "Comments" is blank specifically on "Type 2" but not any other case.

Most of the time, jQuery Validate hides messages automatically as errors get corrected **before** resubmitting the form. In this complex rule, once the error is received, if you go back to "Type 1" the error doesn't disappear.

I tried forcing `.valid()` on "Comments" on the radio's `change()` event. But this has the disadvantage that the first time "Type 2" is selected, you automatically see the error before anything's typed in.

My goal: (1) Do not present the error initially as the user selects Types. (2) If the error is received after Submit, switching to Type1 should auto-hide it.

The auto-hide corrections should be both typing something in (this works correctly), **or** switching the radio button.

```js
jQuery.validator.addMethod("chkType2Comments",checkType2Comments);

$("#myform").validate({
    rules: {
     "comments": {
          chkType2Comments: true
        }
    },
    messages: {
        "comments" : {
            chkType2Comments: "Comments required"
        }
    }
});

function checkType2Comments() {
 var type = $('input[name="type"]:checked').val();
 if (type == '2') {
  if ($('input[name=comments]').val().trim() == '') {
   return false;
  } 
 }
 return true;
}

$('#submitForm').click(function() {
   $('#myform').valid();
})

// Radiobutton switching -- if I remove this, the error doesn't go away on switching back.
// But if I leave this code, the error comes up immediately.
// Goal: Error not initially shown, but if Type is switched afterwards, auto-turned off.
/*
$('input[name=type]').change(function() {
    $('input[name=comments]').valid();
});
*/
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.19.0/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>

<form id="myform">

   <input type="radio" name="type" value="1" /> Type 1 <br/>
   <input type="radio" name="type" value="2" /> Type 2 <br/>
   
   <input type="text" name="comments" />

   <input type="button" id="submitForm" value="submit"/>

</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *"My goal: (1) Do not present the error initially as the user selects Types. (2) If the error is received after Submit, switching to Type1 should auto-hide it."*

So put your `change` handler inside of your `click` handler so that your radio buttons are ignored until the first click of the "submit".

```
$('#submitForm').on('click', function() {

    $('#myform').valid();

    $('[name="type"]').on('change', function() {
        $('[name="comments"]').valid();
    });

});
```

**DEMO:  [jsfiddle.net/5hdoc2wv/2/](https://jsfiddle.net/5hdoc2wv/2/)**